# Method for determining distributions of sum of Normal distribution unknown mean and variance

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I've been trying to complete this question but have been struggling to see how to approach it.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Is there a standard way of approaching and answering questions like this? I've thought about Chi square and T- distributions but their definitions don't seem to be helping me. I know the first one follows a Chi (m+n-2) square distribution, but how do I solve the second one?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For finding the distribution of the first one

$$(m+n-2)\frac{S^2}{\sigma^2}$$
let
$S^2_1=\frac{1}{m-1}\sum_{i=1}^m(X_i-\overline X)^2$ and $S^2_2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{j=1}^n(X_i-\overline X)^2$. Then

$$(m+n-2)\frac{S^2}{\sigma^2}=(m-1)\frac{S_1^2}{\sigma^2}\ +\ (n-1)\frac{S_2^2}{\sigma^2}$$

But as you correctly guessed, each summand of the last equation follows a $\chi_{m-1}^2$ and a $\chi_{n-1}^2$ respectively. And since $X_1\dots X_m$ and $Y_1\dots Y_n$ are independent random samples, we can add up those two distributions to get that

$$(m+n-2)\frac{S^2}{\sigma^2}(m+n-2)\sim \chi_{m+n-2}^2$$

For the last one, remember that if a sample of size $n$ distributes as a $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then $\overline X\sim N(\mu,\frac{\sigma^2}{\sqrt n})$. And that the difference of sample means $\overline X -\overline Y$, where $(X_1\dots X_m)$ and $(Y_1,\dots Y_n)$ are independent samples with distribution $N(\mu_1,\sigma^2)$ and $N(\mu_2,\sigma^2$) respectively, follows a $N(\mu_1-\mu_2,\sigma^2\sqrt{\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}})$. Using this and the previous distribution, you should be able to get the distribution of the last expression.

Comment: Ah, thank you very much!

Comment: So presumably the Confidence Interval follows from the second formula and some reshuffling, dividing by the variance etc?

Comment: @J.Bant Yes. I assume you've heard about pivotal quantities, right? The second expression is almost the pivotal quantity one would use to the confidence interval of $\mu_1-\mu_2$. Make some arrangments so it distributes as a $N(0,1)$ and you'll get it.

Comment: Thank you. So I don't have to use the t distribution at all here? for the CI

Comment: @J.Bant Oh, sorry. I thought that $\sigma^2$ was known. Forget the previous comment. If $\sigma^2$ is unknown, then you should use the second expression as the pivotal quantity for the CI, and then you must use the $T$ distribution as well.